# Getting attributes of an xml file and assigning them to html tags

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have an XML file (PDF converted to XML)

Every word in the XML file has attributes like its "position" and "font". I need to take each of these elements from the XML and print it in HTML. I'm using XSLT for the conversion. But how do I add the same "font" and "position" attributes in HTML?

For example, my XML has a text, say, "name", with a `font-size`, `x` and `y` coordinates. Is it possible for me to populate a CSS dynamically with these values when they are extracted from XML, so that I can display my HTML with this CSS?

Or is there any easier way for this?
I'm completely new to XML, HTML and XSLT.

Here's the format of my XML:

```
<TAG1>
     <TAG2>
         <TAG3 font-name="xyz" x="12.3" y=1.5>
                  EXAMPLE 1:
         </TAG3>
     </TAG2>
</TAG1>
```

Now I want to show the HTML like this:

```
<h1 style="font-name:xyz;top:1.5;left:12.3">
```

I'm able to extract attribute information and the text using XSLT attribute template. But applying the style is the problem here.

Comment: Show us your XML, the desired CSS and what you tried so far!

Comment: I am not sure what "a PDF file, in XML form" is. If it is an XML file, you can *probably* extract the attributes and attach them to each word as inline style. I say probably, because I'm not familiar enough with CSS to be sure about the individual positioning of each word. Perhaps SVG might be a better tool than HTML here?

Comment: @ThomasW : Have added the structure. Could you please help?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I had a PDF file which was converted to XML. Now, I have to work with XML and needs an HTML. Sorry for not being clear before...And, thank you :)

Comment: How does your XSLT look so far? The XML looks made up, as well as does your CSS as there is no `font-name` property. Can you show more realistic stuff?  The reason I ask:  I have a suspicion that the "PDF in XML form" is SVG, and that's something we know and can work with.

Comment: I'm really sorry..I'm not allowed to show the actual XML. In the inline style, I just gave an example of font-name. About the PDF conversion, I converted it using a tool developed within my company and it is pure XML, not SVG....

Comment: Thank you, that was a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm able to extract attribute information and the text using XSLT,
>   Attribute template. But applying the style is the problem here....

Applying the style in the format you have shown should be trivial. Assuming that you are in the context of the `<TAG3>`element, and that the element is properly formed as:

```
<TAG3 font-name="xyz" x="12.3" y="1.5">
                  EXAMPLE 1:
</TAG3>
```

(note the added quotes surrounding the 'y' value), you can add the required attributes to the output as:

```
<h1 style="font-name:{@font-name};top:{@x};left:{@y}">
```

Whether the result has any meaning is a question that I am not qualified to answer..